# get the html code of a certain div in the render event

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, render

There is a way to get the html value of a div in the page render event with many asp:Label's inside?

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // *** Write the HTML into this string builder
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    base.Render(hWriter);
    string valdiv = DivCliente.InnerHtml;
    // *** store to a string
    string PageResult = sb.ToString();
     ...........
}
```

Like this way, I get the whole page in PageResult (that's almost I want), but I only want the html result of a certain div (with a known id), to print that html code(with all those labels that now are rendered as text) into a pdf.

I tried with the InnerHtml property of the div but I get an exception "You can not get the internal value of the div because it's not a Literal"

Any idea?

Thanks!

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on my WebForms coding, but can't you just do `DivCliente.Render(my writer)` or something similar?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.render.aspx

It may have some unintended side effects on the div control's state, I'm not sure.

Why do you need the DIV's contents?

Comment: Thanks it just used DivCliente.RenderControl(hWriter); string result= sb.ToString();
And then I got it! :)

I need the html to print it into a pdf file.